AWS EC2 Instance - Node JS Cloud Watch
I'm having one aws instance for my personal use.
Instance Details:
Platform - Ubuntu
Here, I have created one NODE JS project folder and imported my project using git. Run the server using npm start command.
My server was stopped some time due to error in code. Manually I'm login to server and npm start again.
I want to check which functionality was affected and why it keeps stopping.
How to enable to logs or cloudwatch and catch the user interaction and which functionality is affecing.
Sorry for my bad english.

Did you read the documentation on how to install the CloudWatch Agent? Does your application write logs that would actually be collected by the CloudWatch Agent?
